# How to combine results from multiple solr queries (much like UNION on SQL's)?

Tags: solr

In our search application, I want to allow users to combine their previous search results using AND/OR. Basically combine the results of previously executed queries. How can I achieve this in SOLR?

Comment: Hi Soma, kindly show us what you tried so far and what goes wrong with this. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: That depends on how you're querying. In general, just wrapping both queries within `()` and with `AND` or `OR` between them should work. What have you tried?

Comment: We have 2 queries as follows which we need to merge results:

Comment: Example of the 2 queries: 1. Get the articles in the journal 'Animal Sciences' for latest issue.

Comment: Query 2: Get the articles with key word 'Cow diseases'.  I need to merge the results with AND / OR between this query and the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

If those previous queries affect ranking. If they do affect ranking (can be partial match), you need to combine them together in a main query. There can be only one main query, though it can have subqueries in other variables passed through local parameters.

However, if they are binary (match/not match) queries, such as for categories/filters/facets, then you can use Filter Queries (**fq**) instead. Those you can have several and each one basically reduces matches without affecting ranking.

Comment: Thanks. These are not filter queries, rather two different queries whose results need to be merged